# Cannot get the dependent dropdown value from region dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, opencart

I would like to show the geozone in the registration account step as dropdown menu, just like the zone (region). But the value of the geozone is dependent to what customer choose in the zone (region).

### The Picture

In the process, I already did some modifications to the controller, view, including controller. Just like in the pic below :
[image: Kotamadya/Kabupaten is the geozone field]

The geozone field is Kotamadya/Kabupaten.
But when I choose the region Aceh, the geozone field is not refreshed.

### Error Message

I got error message like below :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

OK

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function
getGeozonesByZoneId() on a non-object in <b>
/home/........../catalog/controller/account/register.php
</b> on line <b>513</b><br />
```

### The Code

In ../controller/account/register.php, I added some modifications as below :

```
public function zone() {
    $json = array();

    $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

    $geozone_info = $this->model_localisation_zone->getZone($this->request->get['zone_id']);

    if($geozone_info)
    {
        $this->load->model('localisation/geo_zone');

        $json = array(
            'country_id'        => $geozone_info['country_id'],
            'name'              => $geozone_info['name'],
            'code'              => $geozone_info['code'],
            'zone'          => $geozone_info['zone_id'],
            'geozone'           => $this->model_localisation_geozone->getGeozonesByZoneId($this->request->get['zone_id']),
            'status'            => $geozone_info['status']      
        );
    }
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

line 513 is :

```
'geozone'           => $this->model_localisation_geozone->getGeozonesByZoneId($this->request->get['zone_id'])
```

I don't know what's wrong with the getGeozonesByZoneId function, because I think I already write the function correctly in ../model/localisation/geo_zone.php as below :

```
    <?php
class ModelLocalisationGeozone extends Model {
    public function getGeozone($zone_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$geo_zone_id . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }       

    public function getGeozonesByZoneId($zone_id) {
        $geozone_data = $this->cache->get('geozone.' . (int)$zone_id);

        if (!$geozone_data) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$zone_id . "'");

            $geozone_data = $query->rows;

            $this->cache->set('geozone.' . (int)$zone_id, $geozone_data);
        }

        return $geozone_data;
    }
}
?>
```

and I already added javascript to register.tpl in view as below :

```
$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').bind('change', function(event, first_time) {
          $.ajax({
              url: 'index.php?route=account/register/zone&zone_id=' + this.value,
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend: function() {
                  $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
              },
              complete: function() {
                  $('.wait').remove();
              },
              success: function(json) {

                  var html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';
                  var selected = false;
                  if (json['geozone'] && json['geozone'] != '') {
                      for (i = 0; i < json['geozone'].length; i++) {
                          html += '<option value="' + json['geozone'][i]['geo_zone_id'] + '"';

                          if (json['geozone'][i]['geo_zone_id'] == '<?php echo $geo_zone_id; ?>') {
                              html += ' selected="selected"';
                              selected = true;
                          }

                          html += '>' + json['geozone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                      }
                  } else {
                      html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
                  }

                  $('select[name=\'geo_zone_id\']').html(html);
                  if(typeof first_time === "undefined" && selected) {
                    $("#register_details_form").validate().element('#register_details_form select[name="geo_zone_id"]');
                  }
              },
              error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
              }
          });
      });

      $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').trigger('change', ['first_time']);
```

anyone can help me to resolve this issue? or maybe have same experiences with me and willing to share your solutions to me?

thanks before in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `model_localisation_zone` instead of `model_localisation_geozone`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I think it should be model_localisation_geozone. Because getGeozonesByZoneId is under class ModelLocalisationGeozone

Comment: But the second variable is not an object (apparently) but the first one is; I can see it being used earlier in your code

Comment: hmm..the object is not created yet?

Comment: @ExplosionPills : your comments guide me to get the solutions. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `model_localisation_zone` (defined variable) instead of `model_localisation_geozone` (not defined), or make sure the latter is defined.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you are forgetting to load model `Geozone` in your `register.php` controller file add this line

```
$this->load->model('localisation/geozone');
```

to `register.php`

before calling function

```
$this->model_localisation_geozone->getGeozonesByZoneId($this->request->get['zone_id'])
```